# Ruby won't update

Tags: ruby

Help! Trying to install Cocoapods on my mac, kept getting an error, thought it might be something to do with having a really old version of Ruby.

Then this happened:

```
% ruby -v
ruby 2.6.10p210 (2022-04-12 revision 67958) [universal.x86_64-darwin22]

% brew upgrade ruby
Warning: ruby 3.2.1 already installed

% ruby -v
ruby 2.6.10p210 (2022-04-12 revision 67958) [universal.x86_64-darwin22]
```

Why is it saying that it's already installed?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it could be that your `$PATH` still points to the old (pre-installed, maybe?) Ruby version.

Try this:

```
echo $PATH
# check if it includes the dir where homebrew installs its pkgs

# if it's not there, add the path to your .zshrc
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH

# close the terminal or, alternatiively
source ~/.zshrc

# check if the path is there
echo $PATH

brew upgrade ruby
```